# Distribution of shoe production

Tags: probability, self-learning

I know that the number of shoes produced in a factory during one week is a random variable with mean $300$.

a) What can I say about the probability that this week’s production will be at least $800$?

b) If in addition I know that the variance of this week’s production is $150$, what can I say about the probability that this week’s production will be between $200$ and $400$?

For a) I understand that I need to compute $P(X >= 800)$ but without any other informations how am I supposed to compute a number ?

Comment: No information about  the general distribution of the random variable ? Maybe normal distribution ?

Comment: I suspect the question may be asking about (a) Markov's inequality and (b)  Chebyshev's inequality, especially if you have recently learnt about them in class

Comment: In fact, Henry, we did see these concepts recently. So I might check on that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further information, you can't compute these probabilities exactly.  You can, however, get some inequalities.  For $a$, for example, let $p$ be the probability that production is at least $800$.  Since production can't be negative we see that the mean production, $\mu$ is at least $p\times 800$.  Thus we have $$800p≤300\implies p≤\frac 38$$.

For $b$ you have more information, so you can do a bit better.  We can invoke [Chebyshev's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_inequality).  We have $\sigma =\sqrt {150}=12.24744871$ and we are interested in $k=\frac {100}{\sigma}=8.164965809$ from which we deduce that $$P(|X-300|≥100)≤\frac 1{8.164965809^2}=.015$$

Thus the probability you want is bounded below by $.985$

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! But shouldn't it be the probability that X-300 is greater than k (i.e. 8.16) in Chebyshev's inequality?

Comment: No...it's $k\sigma$.  The whole idea of these kind of calculations is to get everything in "sigma units".  That works well with normal distributions..as in the usual $z$-score, and it works partially with things like Chebyshev's Inequality, as here.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly $X$ is nonnegative, so Markov's inequality yields $P(X \ge 800) \le \frac{E[X]}{800} = \frac{3}{8}$.

Now can we say anything more about this? We actually can't in the first case. If $0 \le p \le \frac{3}{8}$, we can find a nonnegative integer-valued random variable $X$ with mean $300$ that satisfies $P(X \ge 800) = p$. Simply let $p_2 = 1 - \frac{8}{3} p$ and $p_3 = 1 - p - p_2$ (convince yourself that $p_2$ and $p_3$ are both in the interval $[0, 1]$. Now let $P(X = 800) = p$, $P(X = 300) = p_2$ and $P(X = 0) = p_3$. Then
$$E[X] = 800p + 300p_2 = 800p + 300 - 800p = 300,$$
which is what we wanted.